# Python with Pandas - KeyError: u'the label [422] is not in the [index]

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python code, using pandas module, where I get data from a .csv file into a pandas dataframe. Then, I've to compare values from a list with values of the pandas dataframe. As I have some indexes defined in the list that aren't exist in the dataframe I get the error here:

```
for i in sorted(thresholds.keys()):
    current=acme_current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']
```

KeyError: u'the label [422] is not in the [index]

I need your help to know how can I check if the used index exist before continue to avoid the error. Indexing the dataframe or checking the length are not useful solution in my case.

I tried things like these but they don't work:

```
for i in sorted(thresholds.keys()):
    if acme_current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']:
        current=acme_current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']
```

Or:

```
for i in sorted(thresholds.keys()):
    try:
        current=acme_current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']
    except INDEX_ERROR:
        print "Error"
```

Thanks in advance.

---

Here I let you a complete example (simplified) to see the error. First yoy have to make a source.csv file with this content to be processed.:

```
INVITE,Requests,60,77340232,13674,59,74062475,13504
Retransmissions,0,5387,34,0,114838,2474
100,Trying,57,77039746,13590,59,73752071,13420
180,Ringing,47,37411523,7067,41,36984407,6982
486,Busy Here,2,3689189,819,2,3689238,819
487,Terminated,13,21531195,3687,13,21531766,3687
488,Not Acceptable,0,39326,24,0,30665,22
491,Req Pending,0,121,4,0,118,4
4xx,Client Error,0,1,1,0,1,1
```

Then, a test.py with the code under this text. If I get a way to check if the `current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']` exists before assign it with `current=current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']`, my problem will be solved. Any suggestion?

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd

def compare(name,current_data,thresholds):
    reference=current_data.loc['INVITE','Recent-Server']
    # Check if we have INVITES events
    if reference == '0':
        print "{}: critical status".format(name)
        return

    for i in sorted(thresholds.keys()):
        try:
            current=current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']
            if current != '0':              
                valor=thresholds[i]
        except IndexError:
            print "Index Error"

clear="source.csv"
current = pd.read_csv(clear, names=['Message','Event','Recent-Server','Total-Server','PerMax-Server','Recent-Client','Total-Client','PerMax-Client'])
current.set_index("Message", inplace=True)
responses_all=("100", "180", "181", "182", "183", "200", "5xx")

# Thresholds for each event type
thresholds_mia={
responses_all[0]: ["value1"],   #100 Trying         
responses_all[1]: ["value2"],   #180 Ringing        
responses_all[2]: ["value3"],   #181 Forwarded      
responses_all[3]: ["value4"],   #182 Queued         
responses_all[4]: ["value5"],   #183 Progress       
responses_all[5]: ["value6"],   #200 OK             
responses_all[6]: ["value7"]    #5xx Server Error   
}

# Main
compare("Name",current,thresholds_mia)
```

Comment: `except INDEX_ERROR` seems odd, have you defined `INDEX_ERROR` somewhere else? Likely what you want is `except IndexError`

Comment: You can (1) `except KeyError` (see your error!), or (2) check for existence with `i in acme_current_data.index`. Post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including data files if this doesn't resolve your issue.

Comment: Would be easier if you made a reproducible example, or at least put a header of your dataframe on there.

Comment: Ok, I have made a simple example to reproduce the error. Thanks.

Comment: @scnerd you right about that, but the error continue.

Comment: @AhmedFasih (1) seems not working here. (2) is that I want, but I think it won't work because it is a pandas dataframe. I tried with this:
  if i in current_data.loc.index[i, 'Recent-Server']:
   current=current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']
but I got this:
    if i in current_data.loc.index[i, 'Recent-Server']:
AttributeError: '_LocIndexer' object has no attribute 'index'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for putting a complete code example, that is very helpful. Both suggestions made in my comment work:

### Option 1: use the right exception

If you replace `except IndexError` in your code with `except KeyError`, your code will print "Index Error" five times. Snippet in question:

```
for i in sorted(thresholds.keys()):
    try:
        current = current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']
        if current != '0':
            valor = thresholds[i]
    except KeyError: # <------------------------ use the right exception
        print("Index Error")
```

### Option 2: check the index for membership before accessing

Alternatively, you can check the dataframe's index before accessing, like so:

```
for i in sorted(thresholds.keys()):
    if i in current_data.index:
        current = current_data.loc[i, 'Recent-Server']
        if current != '0':
            valor = thresholds[i]
```

Note here that I check the dataframe's index `i in current_data.index`. What you tried (`i in current_data.loc.index`) is a syntax error, since it's not `loc` that has the index but the dataframe `current_data` itself.

Both these techniques work. I prefer #2.

Comment: Great!! Thanks Ahmed! I tried with them and both solutions works! :) Thanks again!